# Host assets on Google Drive, loop to display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive to host images, it gives me a public URL that I am using on my carousel...this is only an issue if I put an image tag and the image does not belong (the result is a blank image in the carousel)

I know you can use JS to detect if an image is available, but would it be possible to write a loop that would display all images in a certain folder?

Current Example -

```html
 data-src="https://googledrive.com/host/gdrivepath/inside-1.JPG"
```

In a perfect world my client should be able to dump a bunch of images into an assigned folder (assuming images are named sequentially), and no matter the amount the loop would catch them all.

Is this possible with just JS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your web host is Linux based (most are) you could perhaps use https://github.com/Grive/grive and run a script at the server to pull files from the Google Drive to the web host on some sort of schedule?

I'm sorry I cannot be more specific than this, but without knowing more about the environment in question, it's sorta guesswork at the moment.